# Is there a trick to prove that $(x^4+y^4)^{1/2} \leq x^2+y^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

$(x^{4}+y^{4})^{1/2} \leq  x^{2}+y^{2}$

I tried multiplying the original by 1 = $\displaystyle \frac{(x^{4}+y^{4})^{1/2}}{(x^{4}+y^{4})^{1/2}}$, but that just brings me back to the original.

Ive looked up sqrt and exponent laws and can't find anything helpful. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
(x^2 + y^2)^2 &= x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + y^4\\
&= (x^4 + y^4) + 2x^2y^2
\end{align}
$$
Now compare $(x^4 + y^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ with $\left[(x^4 + y^4) + 2x^2y^2\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$, knowing that for all $x, y$, $2x^2y^2\geq 0$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

If $a,b\ge0$ then

$$a\le b\iff a^2\le b^2$$

Comment: Ok, this is much easier than my idea. +1

Comment: Ummmm any more help? :( I'm not sure what to do with that. I know $x^{4}$ and $y^{4}$ > 0 but what else are they less than?

Comment: We have
$$(x^2+y^2)^2=x^4+2x^2y^2+x^4\ge x^4+y^4$$
so we get the desired inequality by taking the square root.@Bob

Answer (score 2):

One way is to interpret the left hand side as the (euclidean) norm of a vector

$$
(x^4+y^4)^{1/2}=\Vert (x^2, y^2)^T \Vert_2. 
$$

You can then apply the triangle inequality for this norm.